# Move wordpress site: Theme options are reset to default on first access

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've setup a script to move a wordpress site. It does all the search-replace on URLs etc. All according to the numerous tutorials out there.

Now to my issue:

The site is looking almost great BUT the options for my themes are reset when I access the site the first time. I can see the database row with the option values being reset when I access the site.

Has anyone stumpled upon the same issue?

Best regards,

Niclas

Answer (score 2):

Your theme could reset it's options when activated. I've seen that bug a few times before with inexperienced wp coders.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas of how to start identifiying where it happens?

Comment: We'll you'll have to read the theme, look for foo_option() functions, if there's a hook for theme activation etc.

Answer (score 0):

The format in which wordpress stores some of its content includes a length parameter of the information. Now if you change some information (URLs when moving to a new domain) the length information will be changed and wordpress can't decode the data. I hade to write a script that iterated over all content (SQL content) and updated the length attribute to the new length.

Sorry. Was some time ago. But it might give a hint to a needing user.